# jQueryUI / jQuery Resizable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use jQuery UI in my MVC 5 project. But I continue to get this .resizable/Resizable is not a function. It is the same for all of jQueryUI functions.. It looks like it keeps trying to see if those function reside in jQuery 3.1.1 instead of jQueryUI?

What I am trying to achieve.

https://jsfiddle.net/vp1dwuv3/

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).resizeable() is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:2:22)
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.1.1.js:3570)
    at process (jquery-3.1.1.js:3638)
```

This is the  of my page when it loads.

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Overview</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="/Content/themes/base/core.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/resizable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/selectable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/accordion.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/button.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/progressbar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working JS sample too?

Comment: Added how it should work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vp1dwuv3/

Comment: @ZachSchulze Are you getting 404 error for jquery ui when you see the console in browser ?

Comment: Nope, when I open Inspect in Chrome there are no errors. As if the file loaded just fine. And when I select the sources tab jquery-ui-1.2.1.js is right there

Comment: Confirmed that it is not loading for some reason. $.ui in the console returns undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it. @SantoshGrampurohit your comment had me searching my code a bit better. I included it 2 times and it was breaking.

Comment: Cool @ZachSchulze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is the same for all of jQueryUI functions.. It looks like it keeps trying to see if those function reside in jQuery 3.1.1 instead of jQueryUI

It means that the jquery ui files are not getting loaded, and as discussed in comments

So check if the path is correct, or the filename is proper, or the file exists at the said path.